# java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.ClassCastException: MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Tags: android

I am  new to android. I have got stuck at the above issue. Please do help me to fix this.

My main Activity:

```
import com.db.appform12.R;
import app.form.appform12.ListUsers;
import app.form.appform12.EditUsers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button regButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMainRegister);
        Button listButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonMainList);
        regButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        listButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonMainRegister :
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), EditUsers.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.ButtonMainList :
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListUsers.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }

    }
```

Complete LogCat trace:

```
12-29 06:23:19.448: D/dalvikvm(2001): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-29 06:23:22.018: I/dalvikvm(2001): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
12-29 06:23:22.018: W/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11352: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
12-29 06:23:22.018: D/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-29 06:23:22.018: I/dalvikvm(2001): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
12-29 06:23:22.018: W/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11358: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
12-29 06:23:22.018: D/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-29 06:23:22.068: I/dalvikvm(2001): Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
12-29 06:23:22.068: W/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9045: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
12-29 06:23:22.088: D/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
12-29 06:23:22.378: I/dalvikvm(2001): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-29 06:23:22.378: W/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 370: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-29 06:23:22.378: D/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-29 06:23:22.378: I/dalvikvm(2001): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-29 06:23:22.378: W/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-29 06:23:22.378: D/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-29 06:23:24.038: D/AndroidRuntime(2001): Shutting down VM
12-29 06:23:24.038: W/dalvikvm(2001): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f44648)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.db.appform12/app.form.appform12.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: app.form.appform12.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: app.form.appform12.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at app.form.appform12.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-29 06:23:24.168: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     ... 11 more
12-29 06:23:48.758: I/Process(2001): Sending signal. PID: 2001 SIG: 9
12-29 06:25:16.559: I/dalvikvm(2061): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
12-29 06:25:16.629: W/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11352: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
12-29 06:25:16.629: D/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-29 06:25:16.629: I/dalvikvm(2061): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
12-29 06:25:16.649: W/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11358: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
12-29 06:25:16.649: D/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-29 06:25:16.699: I/dalvikvm(2061): Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
12-29 06:25:16.719: W/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9045: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
12-29 06:25:16.719: D/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
12-29 06:25:16.879: I/dalvikvm(2061): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-29 06:25:16.899: W/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 370: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-29 06:25:16.899: D/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-29 06:25:16.919: I/dalvikvm(2061): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-29 06:25:16.939: W/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-29 06:25:16.939: D/dalvikvm(2061): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-29 06:25:17.979: D/AndroidRuntime(2061): Shutting down VM
12-29 06:25:18.019: W/dalvikvm(2061): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f44648)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.db.appform12/app.form.appform12.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: app.form.appform12.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: app.form.appform12.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at app.form.appform12.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-29 06:25:18.019: E/AndroidRuntime(2061):     ... 11 more
```

I am not aware of these types of errors. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set `OnClickListener` like this:

```
regButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
listButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

Instead, you need to implement OnClickListener in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    //..
    //then just set this as OnClickListener. and you would need to implement method onClick.
    regButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    listButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `onClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements onClickListener
```

and `@Override onClick(View v)` method

and register like

```
 regButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 listButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Yes did this, but still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this,

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements onClickListener{


regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

              //Your Code..

        }
    });

   }
```

Similarly you can try for `ListButton`.

Answer (score 0):

implement the `onClickListener` to your `MainActivity class` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements onClickListener{

...

@override
public void onClick(View v) {
//handle your click listeners here.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are casting `this` to `OnClickListener` which you should not do.

Follow the steps below to get rid of Errors :

1. Remove cast from this in both button's `OnClickListener`
   i.e `regButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    listButton.setOnClickListener(this);`
2. Remove the `OnClick` method completely from your code
3. Now the code in step 1 would be giving an error in both the `setOnClickListener` methods, so hover over them and from the popup dialog suggestion,choose the one at the last saying "Let <`your_activity_name`> implement `OnClickListener`"
4. Now you'll see an error line under your Activity name on the top(below all your imports), hover over it and among the suggstions dialog choose the one saying "Add unimplementd methods", Now the OnClick method will automatically Override in your code.
5. Now use switch and case to add code for corresponding button clicks..

So the final Code looks as below :

```
//Your import statements here

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMainRegister);
        Button listButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonMainList);
        regButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        listButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent;
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonMainRegister:
                intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), EditUsers.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.ButtonMainList:
                intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListUsers.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }



    }

}
```

**An Off-Question Suggestion** :
Its better to define all your `xml views` starting with a small letter(Recommended) NOT capital..
So Please change `ButtonMainList` to `buttonMainList` ..