# My application in android keeps on crashing

Tags: android

I keep on getting this error in my logcat and don't know why. I don't seem to have any errors in code either. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.admin.trainyourmath, PID: 26931
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.trainyourmath/com.example.admin.trainyourmath.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.admin.trainyourmath.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.admin.trainyourmath.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
                      at com.example.admin.trainyourmath.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: Put show code here,

Comment: Welcome. Please, read the exception ... `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.admin.trainyourmath.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener`. This happen here `com.example.admin.trainyourmath.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)`. So you just need to show `com.example.admin.trainyourmath.onCreate()`

Comment: Show your mainactiivity code here

Comment: Can you  refer this in stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688085/java-lang-runtimeexceptionjava-lang-classcastexception-mainactivity-cannot-be

Comment: Provide code of MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your `MainActivity` as a OnClickListener which it does not implement properly. Add `implements View.OnClickListener` to the end of your `MainActivity` class declaration if it's not already there. Should look something like:

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener`

You also need to implement all the methods of the `View.OnClickListener` so inside your `MainActivity` class add:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Do stuff
}
```